# Change multiple field values of an object

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a collection of objects (say Products) and I want to change the some field values of each object in the collection. I want to define the field name and its corresponding value as below

```
var mapData = new Dictionary<string,string>();
mapData.Add("Name","N");
mapData.Add("Category", "C");
```

For every pre populated Product object's Name and Category fields values needs to be overwritten with N and C. I was trying to do that using LINQ as below and got stuck.

```
    [StepArgumentTransformation]
    public IEnumerable<Product> TransformProductData(Table table)
    {
        var mapData = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        mapData.Add("Name","N");
        mapData.Add("Category", "C");

        foreach(var product in table.CreateSet<Product>)
        {
          var transformedProduct = typeof(product).GetProperties().Select
                    (
                        prop => mapData.First(x => x.Key.Equals(prop.Name))
                        // How do I assign the change the values here ??
                    )
        }

    }
```

Assume the Product Object looks like below

```
    public class Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to associate the property (from the `Product` type) to the value in `mapData`. Once you have the associations defined, you can simply set the value for each product based on the property and the associated value.

Something like this:

```
[StepArgumentTransformation]
public IEnumerable<Product> TransformProductData(Table table)
{
    var mapData = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    mapData.Add("Name","N");
    mapData.Add("Category", "C");

    var prodProcessors = typeof(Product).GetProperties()
      .Where(prop => mapData.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
      .Select(prop => new { Property = prop, Value = mapData[prop.Name]})
      .ToList();

    foreach(var product in table.CreateSet<Product>)
    {
      prodProcessors.ForEach(x => x.Property.SetValue(product, x.Value));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot HashPsi!